# Why doesn't my mortgage journal entries balance?

Tags: mortgage

```
                 Beginning 221,967  
                  Payments  28,250
Interest, taxes, insurance  16,212
            out of balance  -2,394      
     Ending Balance Actual 212,323
```

It is not escrow

Comment: It seems you want the numbers to balance, and rightly so. But, if not in escrow somewhere, how can we even guess? Did you try calling the service provider?

Comment: These could be preliminary "good faith" numbers, they don't always reconcile until the actual funds are issued and the final balance is calculate, from which point the interest rates factor in. Some of the fees like for example taxes and insurance are not finalized until they are and in the meantime, often estimates. So when you are in escrow, as Joe said, then you should be reconciled.

Answer (score 1):

I seems like you made less than full EMI as scheduled
Beginning 221,967
Add Interest, taxes, insurance  16,212 [238179]
Less of Payments 28,250 [209927]
i.e. A principal payment of 12,038 possible it should be 14,432
Reduce by additional principal expected 2394 [212,323]

Answer (score 1):

Your starting *principal* balance was `221,967`

You made `28,250` in payments.  Of that, `16,212` went to interest and escrow (taxes/insurance), leaving `12,038` going to reduce principal.

The "out of balance" is likely a deficit in your escrow account, which means that your taxes and/or insurance were more than your lender anticipated, and they needed to add `2,394` to your loan balance to cover the difference.

So your principal balance is

```
   221,967  (starting balance)
 -  12,038  (principal part of payments)
 +   2,394  (escrow deficit?)
----------
   212,323  (ending balance)
```

That said, a `2,394` deficit seems like a lot on a 200k mortgage; I would definitely get an explanation from the lender to be sure their escrow estimates are correct based on your actual insurance and tax bills.